# How to modify a job without effecting the other jobs deployed on Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

How can I modify and deploy 1 job (ex: rebuild the jar file with changing job A) on SCDF but the other jobs in that jar file are still running.

I'm setting up a Spring Batch Job on Spring Cloud Data Flow. There are multiple jobs (A,B,C,...) in my Spring Batch project. I have built a jar file from my project and deployed it on SCDF. 
I have used --spring.batch.job.names=A/B/C/...when launching tasks to run each job separately.
I have tried on creating a new jar and replace it with the old one but it's not work because the old jar is still running.

I have multiple classes related to multiple job and extends from CommonBatchConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class jobAclass extends CommonBatchConfiguration{
    @Bean
        public Job jobA() {
                return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("jobA ")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(stepA1())
                .build();
        }
    @Bean
    public Step stepA1() {  
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("stepA1")
                .tasklet(taskletA1())
                .build();
    }

    public Tasklet taskletA1() {
        return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }
}

@Configuration
public class jobBclass extends CommonBatchConfiguration{
    @Bean
        public Job jobB() {
                return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("jobB")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(stepB1())
                .build();
        }
    @Bean
    public Step stepB1() {  
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("stepB1")
                .tasklet(taskletB1())
                .build();
    }   
    public Tasklet taskletB1() {
        return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }
}

@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
public class CommonBatchConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
}
```

I expect to modify 1 jobs in file jar and deploy it without effect the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need Composed tasks (configured as batch jobs) in your case and you can have the composed tasks deployed as individual tasks (batch applications). For more details on composed tasks, you can see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-composed-tasks).

The feature of modifying one of the jobs' version without affecting the other tasks is something being addressed in 2.3.x of SCDF and you can watch the epic [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/3406)

Comment: I have modified one job and get a new jar file. After that, I copy it into deploy folder where the url of app_registration point to.It works. However, I have a new problem that the task do not stop while I do "stop the job" using SCDF dashbroad and the status of that job is"STOPPING".Particularly, the log of that "STOPPING" job is still written. Do you have any ideas about it?

Comment: It might be a bug or something related to how your jobs are configured. Could you create an issue on Spring Cloud Data Flow Github with the useful information to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I have found the reason of my problem. The log was still written because the job executed until it finished the current step(My job has 2 steps and the second step was not executed ). However, are there any ways to shut down it (step 1) immediately when I stop the job? I will try on creating the issue on Github as your advise.